# AngularJS: How to make <select> label and value identical

Tags: angularjs

a simple question, for which I am not able to find any appropriate solution out there on the Web.

Having a simple array like

```
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Horse']
```

I need a select list looking like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>...
</select>
```

Doing

```
<select ng-options="animal for animal in Animals">
```

sets only numeric values, but I need the literal values, same as label, because the function is a part of a big project which relies on this, and I have no influence on the rest.

Please help!

Comment: I tried `animal for animal in Animals` and it works as you wish: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8mv8UnOiRdRJKnTiELn - did I miss something about your case?

Comment: @lort he wants to change the option _values_  , your code renders values as 0,1,2

Comment: But the value of the model is the animal name, as wished. If this behavior is necessary for an external library, then ok. But if you will manipulate the data in the controller, the @lort solution is right.

Comment: @lort - one year later I came upon this question again. Can you please convert your comment with the plunker link to an answer so I can upvote and accept it? It's perfectly working. Sorry for being that late...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options`:

```
<select>
  <option value="{{animal}}" ng-repeat="animal in Animals">{{animal}}</option>
</select>
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/PgenyJEZVCh6dGrbQGuD

Comment: -1 read docs... suggest not using ng-repeat. Can be accomplished in `ng-options` expression

Comment: I have considered that, however, I believe to have read somewhere rather NOT TO use ng-repeat for <option>. If somebody can please remind us of why it is not recommended, I would appreciate. Still, +1

Comment: @charlietfl: you say it can be accomplished, but you don't say HOW. And this is the question...

Comment: BarthZalewski...   demo supplied by lort does what you want

Comment: @charlietfl - docs don't say using `ng-repeat` is doing things wrong. It says that you should use `ng-options` "*when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value"*. Question was about contents of `value` attribute, not about model, read carefully and don't give downvotes for legit answers...

Comment: @BarthZalewski - Here is an example of why in most cases `ng-options` should be used: http://plnkr.co/edit/tZDc00rTUkPPhvmQlwwU - when using `ng-repeat`, the model is bound to string representing object. When using `ng-options` the model is bound to an object itself.

Comment: Thank you, it is very informative. I accepted your answer and gave you +1. Have a nice day!